# How should I reassign many-to-many child relationships in Code First Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I can assign a child collection to a *new* parent object and on save the relationships are saved as expected.  However, if the parent object *already exists* and I try the same, the new relationships I would expect to be created are not, and the old relations are still there.

Is the only way for me to do such a change to first work out the items that are being removed/added and then call Remove() and Add() on each?  Or, is there something I'm missing in the below code;

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set;}
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
} 

public class Tests() 
{
    public void Create()
    {
        db.Locations.Add(new Location { Tags = db.Tags.Where(p => p.TagId == 2)}).ToList();
        db.SaveChanges() // correctly saves the new location with TagId 2 attached
    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        var location = db.Locations.Single(p => p.LocationId == 1);
        location.Tags = db.Tags.Where(p => p.TagId == 1).ToList();
        db.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges(); // TagId 2 still attached, rather than TagId 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a many to many relationship between tag and location ?

Comment: @Antoine Yes there is

Answer (score 0):

You need a third table that links tag and location, containing the id of the two tables you'r trying to link, that's a database law, you cannot have an infinit and variable number of foreign keys in each of your tables.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework Code First, which means the third table (many-to-many) exists in the database, but is not an entity in the code.

Comment: Ok ! That's why, in fact you have to specify everything you want to remove  from location.

Comment: @staffordWilliams, you're doing one to many relationship, there is **no** third table here.

Comment: @YTAM There is a third table, its in the database, not the code.  Its the same as this; http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: db.location.deleteObject(db.Location.Where(p => p.tag.Id == 2));

Comment: Ok, I missed the collection in the first data table

Answer (score 0):

The collection needs to have Clear() called on it.

```
public void Edit()
{
    var location = db.Locations.Single(p => p.LocationId == 1);
    location.Tags.Clear(); // added this line
    location.Tags = db.Tags.Where(p => p.TagId == 1).ToList();
    db.Entry(location).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges(); // TagId 1 now correctly attached
}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302707(v=vs.110).aspx);

Clear does the following:

- Sets the IsLoaded flag to false.
- Removes all entities from the collection.
- Detaches relationships between removed entities and the
  owner of the EntityCollection from the ObjectStateManager.
- Removes the owner of the EntityCollection from the related
  entities.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your tests and the behaviour is slightly different here (EF 6.1.3):

If you don'tcall Clear() then the new tags will be added to the collection. However, if there is an already existing tag an DbUpdateException is thrown.

If you call Clear() then only new tags will be associated to the location.

Therefore using Clear() is usually the right thing to do.

See the sample code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class Location
    {
        [Key]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        [Key]
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }

    public class TagLocsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }


    }

    class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TagLocsDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TagLocsDbContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
            context.Tags.Add(new Tag() { });
            context.Tags.Add(new Tag() { });
            context.Tags.Add(new Tag() { });
            context.Tags.Add(new Tag() { });
        }
    }

    public class Tests
    {
        public void Create()
        {
            using (var db = new TagLocsDbContext())
            {
                db.Locations.Add(new Location { Tags = db.Tags.Where(p => p.TagId == 2).ToList() });
                db.SaveChanges(); // correctly saves the new location with TagId 2 attached
            }
        }

        public void Edit(bool clear)
        {
            using (var db = new TagLocsDbContext())
            {
                var location = db.Locations.Single(p => p.LocationId == 1);
                if (clear) location.Tags.Clear();
                location.Tags = db.Tags.Where(p => p.TagId == 1).ToList();
                db.SaveChanges(); // if Clear ran locations = {1}, otherwise it is {1,2}
            }
        }

        public void EditWithConflict()
        {
            using (var db = new TagLocsDbContext())
            {
                var location = db.Locations.Single(p => p.LocationId == 1);
                location.Tags = db.Tags.ToList();
                db.SaveChanges(); //Conflict - will throw an exception
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var initializer = new DbInitializer();
            Database.SetInitializer(initializer);

            var tests = new Tests();
            tests.Create();
            PrintLocation("After create: ", 1);

            tests.Edit(false);
            PrintLocation("After edit without clear: ", 1);

            tests.Edit(true);
            PrintLocation("After edit with clear: ", 1);

            try
            {
                tests.EditWithConflict();
                PrintLocation("After edit with clear: ", 1);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException exc)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown : {0}",exc.Message);
                PrintLocation("After edit with conflicting tags: ", 1);

            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PrintLocation(string afterCreate, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(afterCreate);
            using (var db = new TagLocsDbContext())
            {
                var location = db.Locations.Single(a => a.LocationId == i);
                var tags = string.Join(",", location.Tags.Select(a => a.TagId));
                Console.WriteLine("Location {0} : Tags {1}", location.LocationId, tags);

            }
        }
    }
}
```